# Stop unislider when user clicks play on video

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I am using [Unislider](http://unslider.com/) on my website. One of the slides has a html5 video within it, and I want to stop the slider when the video begins to play. The Unislider documenation shows some properties you can use, in this case I am interested in stop(); but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var slidey = $('#image-slider').unslider({
            speed: 5000,
            delay: 9000,
            fluid: true,
            fade:true
        });

        data = slidey.data('unislider');

        var introvideo = $(".intro-video");

        $(introvideo).on('play', function() {
            data.stop();
        });
});
```

I have also tried:

```
    $(".intro-video").on('play', function() {
        data.stop();
    });
```

As well as:

```
    $(".intro-video").click(function() {
        data.stop();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had spelt unslider incorrect..FML. For anyone interested, this code works just fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var slidey = $('#image-slider').unslider({
            speed: 5000,
            delay: 9000,
            pause: false,
            fluid: true,
            fade:true
        }),
        data = slidey.data('unslider');

        $(".intro-video").on( 'play', function() {
            data.stop();
        });
});
```